# Configuring pocketsphinx gstreamer element

Tags: python, gstreamer, pocketsphinx

I have pocketsphinx running as an element inside a python gstreamer pipeline, something along the lines of:

```
launch_config = 'gconfaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! vader name=vad auto-threshold=true ! pocketsphinx name=asr ! fakesink'
pipeline = gst.parse_launch(launch_config)
```

Using `gst-inspect`, I can see the pocketsphinx element has several properties (such as a language model file and dictionary file), but that these are *separate* from command-line options you might normally pass to the executable.

I would like to change the log file that pocketsphinx uses, but this is only an option to `gst-pocketsphinx`, not the `pocketsphinx` gstreamer element.

```
$ gst-inspect-0.10 pocketsphinx
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:

gst-pocketsphinx \
    -samprate 8000 \
    -cmn prior \
    -fwdflat no \
    -bestpath no \
    -maxhmmpf 2000 \
    -maxwpf 20 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
<snip>
-logfn
```

How can I pass the `logfn` argument to the pocketsphinx gstreamer element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use latest pocketsphinx 5prealpha, it supports gstreamer-1.0 and it uses gstreamer logging framework, so you can manage it as any other gstreamer element.